# Error 'The data could not be converted.' when trying to create an envelope via SOAP API

Tags: docusignapi

We’re getting an error when trying to create an envelope via the SOAP API. The message is “The data could not be converted.” We are uploading a PDF file.

This started on 9/9 around 5:18 PM ET.

Before that it was working fine. We have not made any changes to this program recently.

I know you would typically post code in your question, but in this case the service was working fine for years and stopped working.

Comment: What DocuSign environment are you hitting?  Is this through your developer account hitting demo.docusign.net or a different environment?  If it's demo I'd give it some time and it's probably a server error that will be fixed on DocuSign's end soon, if not already...

Comment: No, this is production. The application was created before integrator keys were required. It looks like they intentionally made it stop working because it does not use an integrator key.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: No, this is still an issue